# trac git repository browser not working

Tags: git, mod-wsgi, trac

I am trying to setup Trac 1.0.13 on Apache with mod_wsgi. I want to be able to browse local git repos with the BrowserModule.

My trac.ini has

```
[git]
cached_repository = enabled
persistent_cache = enabled
[trac]
repository_type = git
repository_dir = /path/to/repo.git
repository_sync_per_request = false
```

However when I try to browse the repo, Trac takes a long time and most of the time prints out `git backend not available`. In the Trac log

```
Trac[git_fs] ERROR: GitError: Could not retrieve GIT version (tried to execute/parse 'git --version' but got OSError(12, 'Cannot allocate memory'))
```

When it does load the repo, the dates are all wrong and I can't actually view any files as well. I have tried manully running

```
trac-admin /path/to/trac/env changeset added default $(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

but nothing changed.

Other than this problem, Trac is working as expected.

Edit: after using full path of the repo (instead of default) in the trac-admin command the repository appears properly in the BrowserModule. However the `GIT backend not available` error still occurs frequently.

Comment: Did you saw `Cannot allocate memory` in the error message? Did you did anything regarding this? Is the machine low on memory? Did you try to increase it?

Comment: `OSError(12, 'Cannot allocate memory')`

Comment: Unfortunately the server in question is limited to 512M. I was hoping for the problem to be due to some misconfiguration on my part rather than a hardware limitation.